# Can't find ASP.NET Design View for MonoDevelop

Tags: asp.net, mono, monodevelop, visualdesigner

I installed MonoDevelop and want to use its design view editor. After a bit of browsing I came accross ASP.NET Visual Designer which is supposed to be a part of the IDE. I used the Ubuntu Software Center to install the MonoDevelop application, so I guess it should have downloaded the latest version.

Here is the extract from the mono develop [website](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET_Visual_Designer).

> AspNetEdit does not aim to be a complete IDE. After being developed as
>   a proof-of-concept standalone editor, it now has been integrated into
>   MonoDevelop

How can I switch to the designer view?

After opening the IDE I am unable to find the designer view anywhere. Do I need to install some kind of a add-in for this?

Comment: I don't think that the designer is included in the current releases of Mono. I would say that what you see on that page is old and must have been removed from the stable releases.

Comment: @lanks Thanks for the reply. So, is there any design view support for ASP.NET in MonoDevelop?

Comment: I don't think so. I know that when you are in the template view you can bring up a side pane with all of the asp.net controls. You can select controls and it will insert the control source into your template source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monodevelop lacks a lot on this area. A lot of developers, like me, don't use visual designer a lot but I consider important for some people. **MD don't have it and also html/css editor is very limited right now** but improvements are [planned](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/TODO) (a lot of cool stuff).

MD as been evolving fast these days but more focused on MonoTouch.

For now you could use and external html/css editor for now. I still use Visual Studio 2010 for this.

Answer (score 2):

AspNetEdit can install by Add-ins from http://mjhutchinson.com/files/md/main.mrep

Comment: How to install it?