# ASP.NET visual designer for Monodevelop - Where? How?

Tags: asp.net, mono, monodevelop

I can't find any recent resources on the monodevelop ASP.NET visual designer.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801237/cant-find-asp-net-design-view-for-monodevelop) is from 2012, and the the link to the plugin in the bottom answer doesn't work.
The [only documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/aspnet_visual_designer/) on it that I was able to find hasn't been updated since 2008.

I also looked around the Monodevelop source code repositories and did find [the plugin](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/extras/AspNetEdit), however it appears to not have gotten any updates in years.

I would like to know - is there any recent development?
Would what we have even work with a more recent version of Monodevelop, such as 5.5 or 5.6? If it does, where would I find instructions on building it? (I have tried, it unfortunately did not work)